# Biqquery: Some rows belong to different partitions rather than destination partition

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, partitioning, airflow

I am running a Airflow DAG which moves data from GCS to BQ using operator GoogleCloudStorageToBigQueryOperator i am on Airflow version 1.10.2.

This task moves data from MySql to BQ(Table partitioned), all this time we were partitioned by  `Ingestion-time` and the incremental load for past three days were working fine when the data was loaded using Airflow DAG.

Now we changed the partitioned type to be `Date or timestamp` on a DATE column from the table, after which we have started getting this error, since we are getting the incremental load to have data for last three days from MySql table, I was expecting the BQ job to Append the new records or recreate the partition with 'WRITE_TRUNCATE' which i have tested earlier and both of them fail with below error message.

`Exception: BigQuery job failed. Final error was: {'reason': 'invalid', 'message': 'Some rows belong to different partitions rather than destination partition 20191202'}.`

I wont be able to post the code since, all modules being called based on JSON parameter, but here is what I am passing to the operator for this table with other regular parameters

```
create_disposition='CREATE_IF_NEEDED',
time_partitioning = {'field': 'entry_time', 'type': 'DAY'}
write_disposition = 'WRITE_APPEND' #Tried with 'WRITE_TRUNCATE'
schema_update_options = ('ALLOW_FIELD_ADDITION',
                                 'ALLOW_FIELD_RELAXATION')
```

I believe these are the fields which might cause the issue, any help on this is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

When using Bigquery partitioned tables by Date or timestamp, you should specify the [partition to load the data](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/creating-column-partitions#creating_a_partitioned_table_when_loading_data).
E.g

```
table_name$20160501
```

Also, your column value should match the partition, for example, if you create this table:

```
$ bq query --use_legacy_sql=false "CREATE TABLE tmp_elliottb.PartitionedTable (x INT64, y NUMERIC, date DATE) PARTITION BY date"
```

The column **date** is the column-based for the partition and if you try to load the next row

```
$ echo "1,3.14,2018-11-07" > row.csv
$ bq "tmp_elliottb.PartitionedTable\$20181105" ./row.csv
```

You will get this error due you are loading data from **2018-11-07** when you are using the partition **20181107**

```
Some rows belong to different partitions rather than destination partition 20181105
```

I suggest to use the following **destination_project_dataset_table** value and verify if the data match to the partition date.

```
destination_project_dataset_table='dataset.table$YYYYMMDD',
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, what I found was our Airflow framework does pass the $YYYYMMDD value with today's execution date to the destination_project_dataset_table if the table is partitioned which is why I was getting the above-mentioned error, even though I had logic to only send data for that particular partition the framework was automatically adding $YYYYMMDD to the destination dataset. 
So basically destination_project_dataset_table variable is templated.